# CPLEX OPL Crashing after running for 150 hrs

Tags: cplex, opl

I am running a CPLEX OPL optimisation problem with the following statistics.

Constraints - 1,953,889

Variables -1,272,755
Binary      -  849,525
Other       -  423,230

Non Zero Coefficients - 193,748,215

This should not be a large problem for CPLEX. However the program has been crashing and closing itself after about 150 hrs on a relatively speced up machine running on 32 threads. By that time it generates several solutions but the gap is more than the tolerance. Hence it does not stop or write a solution.

Any suggestions on where I should look for possible causes for the crash. Since it is an academic work I do not mind the run time that much for now, but due to the crash I am not getting the required result.

A copy of the engine log after about 4 hrs or run on a lower speced machine below, still no solutions. Solutions would start after more hours of run :

```
    CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_AbsMIPGap                0.29999999999999999
    CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap                   0.29999999999999999
    Found incumbent of value 0.000000 after 3.09 sec. (1521.84 ticks)
    Presolve has eliminated 1426401 rows and 29721 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427050 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427155 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427199 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427221 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427232 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427248 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427251 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427253 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427258 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427262 rows and 31116 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1427266 rows and 32490 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1430448 rows and 38009 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 1432694 rows and 44922 columns...
    Presolve has improved bounds 1 times...
    Presolve has eliminated 1435876 rows and 50440 columns...
    Presolve has improved bounds 1 times...
    Aggregator has done 3301 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 6701 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 10101 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 13601 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 17201 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 20801 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 24401 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 28001 substitutions...
    Aggregator has done 31701 substitutions...
    Tried aggregator 2 times.
    MIP Presolve eliminated 1435876 rows and 50440 columns.
    MIP Presolve modified 74517 coefficients.
    Aggregator did 32340 substitutions.
    Reduced MIP has 930123 rows, 1189975 columns, and 7898041 nonzeros.
    Reduced MIP has 814175 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 811870 indicators.
    Presolve time = 661.63 sec. (360393.30 ticks)
    Elapsed time = 58.25 sec. (10001.33 ticks) for 22% of probing
    Elapsed time = 153.92 sec. (20001.67 ticks) for 39% of probing
    Probing changed sense of 405935 constraints.
    Probing time = 287.91 sec. (23644.42 ticks)
    Presolve has eliminated 405935 rows and 436985 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 441536 rows and 436985 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 441536 rows and 436985 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 441536 rows and 436985 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 441536 rows and 436985 columns...
    Tried aggregator 1 time.
    MIP Presolve eliminated 441536 rows and 436985 columns.
    MIP Presolve modified 5205 coefficients.
    Reduced MIP has 863472 rows, 752990 columns, and 7759378 nonzeros.
    Reduced MIP has 377190 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 436985 indicators.
    Presolve time = 1890.88 sec. (3757607.10 ticks)
    Probing time = 5.09 sec. (1388.12 ticks)
    Presolve has eliminated 374885 rows and 0 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 374885 rows and 0 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 374885 rows and 0 columns...
    Presolve has eliminated 374885 rows and 0 columns...
    Tried aggregator 1 time.
    MIP Presolve eliminated 374885 rows and 0 columns.
    MIP Presolve modified 2925 coefficients.
    Reduced MIP has 519637 rows, 752990 columns, and 7068783 nonzeros.
    Reduced MIP has 377190 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 405935 indicators.
Presolve time = 336.31 sec. (381386.49 ticks)
Elapsed time = 84.47 sec. (10000.67 ticks) for 15% of probing (2117 vars fixed)
Probing fixed 2816 vars, tightened 2811 bounds.
Probing time = 103.34 sec. (13393.56 ticks)
Clique table members: 4287422.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 77.58 sec. (97495.54 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                            0.0000   3.03510e+10              --- 
      0     0   1.94753e+09  3138        0.0000   1.94753e+09      447     --- 
      0     0   1.86782e+09  3461        0.0000    Cuts: 2714    32033     --- 
      0     0   1.73002e+09  3823        0.0000    Cuts: 2119    70710     --- 
      0     0   1.64243e+09  3774        0.0000    Cuts: 1406    96161     --- 
      0     0   1.54953e+09  3656        0.0000    Cuts: 1438   135551     --- 
      0     0   1.51355e+09  3721        0.0000     Cuts: 623   187203     --- 
      0     0   1.50421e+09  3771        0.0000    Cuts: 1205   217726     --- 
      0     0   1.50040e+09  3780        0.0000    Cuts: 1036   263711     --- 
      0     0   1.49560e+09  3796        0.0000    Cuts: 1861   938508     --- 
      0     0   1.48903e+09  3874        0.0000    Cuts: 2132   949751     --- 
      0     0   1.47356e+09  3946        0.0000    Cuts: 2100   963837     --- 
      0     0   1.47166e+09  3949        0.0000    Cuts: 1245   971389     --- 
      0     0   1.46933e+09  3959        0.0000    Cuts: 2000   979763     --- 
      0     0   1.45714e+09  3999        0.0000     Cuts: 995   991782     --- 
      0     0   1.45483e+09  3961        0.0000    Cuts: 1165   997402     --- 
      0     0   1.44372e+09  4013        0.0000    Cuts: 1080  1009129     --- 
      0     0   1.43962e+09  4044        0.0000    Cuts: 1193  1020451     --- 
      0     0   1.43731e+09  3881        0.0000     Cuts: 878  1031579     --- 
      0     0   1.43630e+09  4036        0.0000     Cuts: 835  1348408     --- 
      0     0   1.43194e+09  4019        0.0000    Cuts: 1388  1501001     --- 
      0     0   1.43062e+09  4011        0.0000    Cuts: 1491  1614522     --- 
      0     0   1.42933e+09  4038        0.0000     Cuts: 801  1623805     --- 
      0     0   1.42875e+09  3979        0.0000     Cuts: 191  1711316     --- 
      0     0   1.42785e+09  3982        0.0000    Cuts: 2325  1727702     --- 
      0     0   1.42676e+09  4016        0.0000    Cuts: 1066  1765973     --- 
      0     0   1.42652e+09  3858        0.0000     Cuts: 184  1877913     --- 
      0     0   1.42334e+09  3972        0.0000     Cuts: 891  1931686     --- 
      0     0   1.42322e+09  4011        0.0000    Cuts: 1078  1939771     ---
```

Comment: It is very difficult to know whether any problem will be 'difficult' for any solver. There are problems with millions of variables that can be solved quickly by any of the commercial solvers, and there are problems of maybe 1000 variables that are still unsolved research problems. The excerpt of the log shows it still pre-solving - did it get to start the B&B? Having said that, what caused it to crash? What investigations have you done? How much memory do you have and how much was used? Using 32 threads is probably a bad idea as it will use much more memory for probably little speedup.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for your comment. Please see the rest of the log below, as I mentioned I am now running it in a lower speced machine running only on 4 threads, This is the rest after  about 58 hrs:

Comment: Presolve time = 336.31 sec. (381386.49 ticks)
Elapsed time = 84.47 sec. (10000.67 ticks) for 15% of probing (2117 vars fixed)
Probing fixed 2816 vars, tightened 2811 bounds.
Probing time = 103.34 sec. (13393.56 ticks)
Clique table members: 4287422.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 77.58 sec. (97495.54 ticks)

Comment: Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                            0.0000   3.03510e+10              --- 
      0     0   1.94753e+09  3138        0.0000   1.94753e+09      447     --- 
...
      0     0   1.42322e+09  4011        0.0000    Cuts: 1078  1939771     ---